# Análisis sintáctico de una oración muy compleja (con un árbol)

Tags: sintaxis

Estoy tratando de analizar las oraciones en la frase :

> me temo que el agua fresca no sea la mejor solución para curar la quemadura que se hizo con la cacerola llena de aceite hirviendo

Pero después de unos días, mi mente se volvió en una tostada... Estoy muy inseguro sobre la calidad de este análisis.

[image: su naturaleza en izquierda y su función en derecha]

Si alguién tiene el coraje de ayudarme diciéndome lo que es falso y lo que es correcto, usted será un shah.

Cordialmente.

Comment: Pues yo diría que tu análisis es bastante correcto...

Comment: Una alternativa https://visl.sdu.dk/visl/es/parsing/automatic/trees.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu análisis parece bastante correcto. Lo mejor en estos casos es ir descomponiendo el problema en partes más pequeñas, con la vieja táctica de "divide y vencerás". Así que vamos allá.

> Me temo que el agua fresca no sea la mejor solución para curar la quemadura que se hizo con la cacerola llena de aceite hirviendo.

La primera frase es:

> Me temo X.

Aquí se usa el verbo *[temer](https://dle.rae.es/temer)*, que es transitivo y usado más como pronominal, de ahí el *me* inicial. Así que X es el complemento directo de la oración. Descompongamos X:

> El agua fresca no es Y.

Cambio el verbo a indicativo para mejor comprensión de la frase. Aquí la estructura es sencilla: oración copulativa tipo "X [no] es Y", donde Y es el atributo de X. Descompongamos Y:

> La mejor solución para Z.

Aquí tenemos un [sintagma](https://dle.rae.es/sintagma) nominal *la mejor solución*, seguida de Z que, como bien has dicho, en este caso es una oración subordinada sustantiva con el verbo en infinitivo (equivaldría a "la mejor solución para eso"), introducida por *[para](https://dle.rae.es/para)* en su acepción 4. Descomponemos Z:

> [...] cura la quemadura W.

Cambio el verbo y supongo un sujeto elidido. Analizando, aquí W sería un complemento adjetival de *quemadura*, que a su vez sería el complemento directo de *[curar](https://dle.rae.es/curar)*, verbo transitivo. Descomponemos W:

> Se la hizo con la cacerola llena de aceite hirviendo.

La preposición *[con](https://dle.rae.es/con)* denota el medio, modo o instrumento que sirve para hacer algo, por lo que efectivamente introduce un complemento circunstancial de modo. ¿Cómo se hizo la quemadura? Con la cacerola de aceite hirviendo. A partir de aquí ya no tenemos más frases subordinadas. Simplemente *hirviendo* es el adjetivo de *aceite*, *llena* es adjetivo de *cacerola*, y *de aceite hirviendo* es un [sintagma](https://dle.rae.es/sintagma) preposicional que complementa al adjetivo *llena*.